# Python Change how string is printed

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, date, string-formatting

I have  a string output from another program that shows the date as

```
16/05/03 # (YY/MM/DD)
```

and I wish to change it to

```
03/05/16 #(DD/MM/YY)
```

and here is how the date is supplied

```
(date = info[4].replace('"', '')
```

i have tried

```
dates = str(date)[::-1]
```

but that gave me an output of

```
 40/50/61
```

not quite what I wanted

any ideas using a minimal code as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> '/'.join('16/05/03'.split('/')[::-1])
'03/05/16'
```

or

```
>>> '/'.join(reversed('16/05/03'.split('/')))
'03/05/16'
```

or using `datetime` library:

```
>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime('16/05/03', '%y/%m/%d'), '%d/%m/%y')
'03/05/16'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using datetime give you alot more control with changing the format to suite what you want.

```
import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('16/05/03', '%y/%m/%d')
print d.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```